# Django 1.1 (Ubuntu Linux) dev server not showing media files -- I've looked in the other answers

Tags: django

I have scoured the Django documentation and SO questions.
I am trying to serve css and images on local dev server.  I believe I have settings.py and urls.py correct:

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'media/')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash if there is a path component (optional in other cases).
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com", "http://example.com/media/"
#MEDIA_URL = ''
MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': '/media/'
        }),
    )
```

Checking headers I get this:
    http://localhost:8000/media/style.css

```
GET /media/style.css HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:8000

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Ubuntu; X11; Linux i686; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0

Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1

Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

DNT: 1

Connection: keep-alive

Referer: http://localhost:8000/hotels/select_hotel

Cookie: SESS382051e6e1ed8806a7f7ff8f96fa26b4=imttngg6l6ks88q89fgabsn0d3; has_js=1

Cache-Control: max-age=0



HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND

Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2011 15:41:38 GMT

Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.6.5

Content-Type: text/plain

Content-Length: 32
```

-
So where am I going wrong?

This is my directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 jgoldstick jgoldstick  4096 2011-12-13 11:06 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 jgoldstick jgoldstick 38925 2011-12-13 10:50 headers.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 jgoldstick jgoldstick  4096 2011-12-13 10:50 .
-rw-r--r--  1 jgoldstick jgoldstick  6948 2011-12-13 07:56 edynamic_logo.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 jgoldstick jgoldstick    24 2011-12-12 13:18 style.css
jgoldstick@jgoldstick-desktop:~/code/python/django/ETG_Offer_entry/media$ pwd
/home/jgoldstick/code/python/django/ETG_Offer_entry/media
```

Comment: Why would you be using Django 1.1? It's two years out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the urls.py you should use the MEDIA_ROOT instead of '/media/' as document_root parameter, that should solve it, if not check that the MEDIA_ROOT exists (and you have access to it)

Note: MEDIA_ROOT should be an absolute path

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            'show_indexes': True
        }),
    )
```

in settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
```

Comment: I changed to settings.MEDIA_ROOT and still have same result

Comment: updated mine too, you should check that PROJECT_PATH is correct too

Comment: PROJECT_PATH is correct since it is used in other places like this: PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Comment: try sending show_indexes=True to django.views.static.serve and get http://localhost:8000/media/ you should get the folder index... if not, what do you get?

Comment: I get 401 -- Unauthorized.  My permissions on the directory are drwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 1):

The value for the `'document_root'` key must be the full filesystem path (i.e. `MEDIA_ROOT`), not just `'/media/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided the answers, but you should really:

1. Upgrade to django 1.3 and use [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)
2. If you must use 1.1, use the [django-staticfiles](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-staticfiles/) app.

Both will go a long way when you move to production.

Comment: I'm pretty new to django, so I was hesitant to move to 1.3, but I think I will look into this.  Thanks all for your help